# ES6 template strings

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I am currently trying to reverse a string. My output needs to be olleh. In repl I get unexpected token. I was wondering why that is because I am trying to code in ES6.

```
reverseString(str) => {  
  return str.split('').reverse().join('');
};

reverseString('hello');
```

Comment: That's not the syntax for an arrow function. This question also has nothing to do with template literals, why have you given it that name?

Comment: Always read documentation before you use something you are not familiar with (arrow functions): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions .

Comment: I am currently trying to learn Javascript ES6 and what is wrong with the name?

Comment: @Michael: Since your code doesn't even contain template literals, how is the title related to your problem?

Comment: Why does it need to be template literals?

Comment: Oh I am sorry guys I forgot to changed the title from my last question.

Comment: Man, StackOverflow has started to go crazy with the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions can't be named. They're short for anonymous functions.

Either use the old syntax of named functions.

```
function reverseString(str) {  
  return str.split('').reverse().join('');
};

reverseString('hello');
```

Or assign the arrow function to a variable.

```
var reverseString = (str) => {  
  return str.split('').reverse().join('');
};

reverseString('hello');
```

Comment: var reverseString = (str) => str.split('').reverse().join(''); works for me too.

Comment: Thanks this helped me alot

Comment: re: "_Arrow functions can't be named_":  `var double=a=>a*2; alert(double.name);`... ES6 is cool.